# Catch "Back" event in browser and load different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hashbang

I've been working on a project using the hashbang (`#!`) method to skip though pages. Basically there is only 1 page, and when you click to go to a diffrent page, you stay on the page, but the URL changes, e.g. from `index.html#home` to `index.html#about` and new content is loaded via AJAX/JSON. All works well, but if I go "back" (or forward) in the browser, only the page in the URL changes, but my jQuery isn't fired to reload the content.

What I need is some code that will handle both the back and forward actions in all browsers, so that I can fire the function to load the page from jQuery. How do I do this?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) does this all quite well and includes HTML5's pushState.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks! Andrew's tip about history.js suited my needs perfectly! Andrew; if you can add your comment as answer I can accept it..

Comment: thanks, just made an answer `:)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) is a great & well-maintained jQuery plugin that supports the new [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and falls back gracefully to using hash URLs instead when the History API isn't supported. Works in just about every browser (even IE 6).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event. It fires when the hash is changed. **However,** you should only do this for Internet Explorer 8 support.

Internet Explorer 7 does not support `hashchange`, so you can't rely on that. As for Internet Explorer 9, it (along with Chrome, Safari and Firefox, of course) supports the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), which you [should be using](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) instead. It keeps your URLs clear, short and semantic, while enabling elegant Back/Forward button support.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery-Plugin that seems to be doing exactly what you want.

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

It was the highest voted answer for the questing [What is the best back button jQuery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin)